# CSS Selector cant be applied

Tags: css, tags

Hi all could some please tell me where I am going wrong in the following code. I am trying to apply the following css styles to my page as below my issue is getting it to work properly.

I understand #cookieTerms is a selector which stops the elements being mixed up with the sites main style.css elements.

I thought to call these you would wrap your code in the tag

```
<div id="CookieTerms"></div>
```

but so far no luck for me. My simple code and output is below. Any help much appreciated guys.

```
<style type="text/css">
#cookieTerms{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#DDD;display:none;width:100%;background:rgb(5,5,5);color:#DDD;margin-top:0;padding-top:4px;overflow:auto;}
#cookieTerms .inner{margin:auto;width:960px;}
#cookieTerms div.big{padding-left:5px;float:left;width:680px;}
#cookieTerms div div{padding-left:5px;float:left;width:110px;}
#cookieTerms div h5, #cookieTerms div p{font-size:14px;}
#cookieTerms div h5{font-size:18px;}
#cookieTermsagree{font-size:16px;color:#000;border-top:none;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;background-image:url(../images/goldBar.png);cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;width:100px;}
#cookieTermsagree:hover{background-image:url(../images/greenBar.png);}
#cookieTerms a:link, #cookieTerms a:visited{color:#f6A21D;}
}
</style>
</head>

<div id="CookieTerms">
<div id='inner'><div><h5>Cookies Policy</h5></div><div id='big'>
  <p>Like most websites we use cookies blah blah. <a href='cookies.html'>Tell me more about cookies</a>.</p></div><div><p id='cookieTermsagree'>Close Cookie Message</p></div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ids are case-sensitive. You named the id CookieTerms (with uppercase `C`), but you select the id `cookieTerms` (with lowercase `c`).

Change your id (or the selectors...) to:

```
<div id="cookieTerms">
```

Comment: thanks for he swift reply if I make that mod it simply outputs nothing. Is there anything else I missed?

Comment: @DebraMedien Yeah, you use a `display: none;` in your #cookieTerms selector... No wonder... Remove it then.

Comment: duh silly me thanks this output I pinched from an old j query script works now perfectly. I would vote you up but I only joined this great forum today so cant till I make so many posts. So cheers again.

Comment: @DebraMedien But you could accept the answer in 5 minutes. Btw. I thought 16 reputation would be enough? Minimum is 15?

Answer (score 0):

The case on your ID doesn't match the CSS.

It should be (if I understand your problem correctly):

```
<div id="cookieTerms">
    <div id='inner'><div><h5>Cookies Policy</h5></div>
    <div id='big'>
        <p>Like most websites we use cookies blah blah. <a href='cookies.html'>Tell me more about cookies</a>.</p></div><div><p id='cookieTermsagree'>Close Cookie Message</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oops, got beat to the punch apparently.